# How to use PHP variable in Swagger Annotations

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-php

First of all am so excited about this Swagger PHP, very expressive!

Is there any way we can give PHP variables within swagger annotations.

Below is my code:

```
define('API_PATH', '/api/demo');

/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 * basePath="{API_PATH}",
 * host="11.7.11.16:xxxx",
 * schemes={"http"},
```

Tried giving like $api_path inside annotation as well but its taking as string and API call is failing....

```
basePath="$api_path",
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider using the constant:

in constants.php

```
 define('API_PATH', ''/api/demo");
```

in api.php

```
/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(basePath=API_PATH, ...)
 */
```

Which can be loaded using the bootstrap option:

```
$ swagger --bootstrap constants.php api.php
```

Comment: Thanks Bob will try it and let u know! :)

Comment: yes i tried that but didn't worked for my i have permission issues in my work station but i did another fix for that... anyway thanks for info!